# Apache 2.4 and Yii 2: Using pretty URLs without htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite, yii2, apache2.4

As I have full access to an Apache 2.4 server and following Apache Foundation [recommendations](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when), I would like to get Yii2's pretty URL working **without** writing any `htaccess` file. I'm particularly interested in having:

```
http://<my_domain>/yii/frontend/web/index.php?=<module>/<controller>/<view><params>
```

Turned into:

```
http://<my_domain>/web/<module>/<controller>/<view><params>
```

Yii2 perfectly handles the dynamic `<params>` stuff but we still need Apache to rewrite the path, so I wrote:

In VirtualHost:

```
<Directory />
    Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride none
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^yii/frontend/web(/.*)?$ web$1
</Directory>
```

And in `/conf-available/yii.conf`, for either hiding `index.php` or passthrough file/directory requests:

```
<Directory "/yii/frontend/web">
    AllowOverride none
    Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
</Directory>
```

The results:

- `http://<my_domain>/web`: Not Found Error.
- `http://<my_domain>/yii/frontend/web`: Works (but does not rewrite).
- `http://<my_domain>/yii/frontend/web/<any_valid>`: Not Found Error (and does not rewrite).

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question title is a bit misleading, because even though you're not using `.htaccess`, you are effectively putting its contents into `httpd.conf` or some other Apache configuration file.